# Regression with proportional variables - advice on logit transform

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm looking to run a regression in which both my independent and dependent variables are probabilities. As a side note, ideally, I would use the beta regression, but since I am using Python there isn't yet a stable implementation for it. I was thinking of running a linear regression with logit transformed variables and was wondering if I should logit transform both the independent and dependent variables, or just the dependent. In general, how should I think through processes like this? As a bonus, are there different situations in which these variables should be logit transformed vs log transformed?

Comment: the reason why I stopped using python and started using R is that every time I wanted to use some fancier statistical method it was implemented in R but in python. I don't want to start language wars, but it is a consideration. You can always just call that one r function you need from python, without moving your whole workflow there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is really  a question about whether the conditional mean of the response variable (in whatever form) is adequately modelled as a linear function of the predictor variable (in whatever form). There is no automatic need to logit transform one if you do the other.  By the same token, there is no need to log transform $X$ if you have log transformed $Y$ - again it is a question of adequacy of the linear approximation to the true conditional mean function.

Maybe you can draw scatterplots $(f(X),g(Y))$ of various transformations of your variables (not limited to logit), and overlay the LOESS smooths to get some ideas.  The least curved LOESS smooths should indicate better combinations with which to apply ordinary linear regression.